# Rails searchkick dropdown not showing expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my rails app, I have used searchkick for search & auto dropdown population, all are working properly but showing only five items, on my console showing 20 items which I declared on my controller `limit: 20` but showing only 5 items visually.

model:

```
class DegreeName
   searchkick match: :word_start, searchable: [:name]
end
```

controller

```
def drop_name
    render json: DegreeName.search(params[:q], {
        fields: ["name"],
        limit: 20,
    }).map(&:name)
end
```

view

```
<%= text_field_tag :name, params[:q], id: "drop" %>
```

coffee script

```
$ ->
$('#drop').typeahead
displayKey: 'name'
remote: "/degree/drop_name?q=%QUERY"
```

how to show 20 items on dropdown?

Console

[image]

Comment: how you handled that code in the view?

Comment: @Sravan I have updated my code

Comment: and where you kept `console.log()`

Comment: @Sravan I have uploaded one screenshot, would you please check

Comment: try returning a hash in the response,
`render json: DegreeName.search(params[:q], {
        fields: ["name"],
        limit: 20,
    }).map do |object|
       { name: object.name} 
     end`

Comment: @Sravan Showing on the console but on dropdown showing undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129103/discussion-between-sravan-and-alfa).

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, got it working by setting the limit in typeahead to 20 and the limit on searchkick to 10. Typeahead shows only 5 results by default.

javascript

```
$('#stations-search').typeahead null,
    name: 'station'
    displayKey: 'title'
    source: stations.ttAdapter()
    limit: 20
```

controller

```
render json: Station.search(params[:query],
      autocomplete: true,
      limit: 10})
    .map{|station|{title: station.title}}
```

I don't know why but setting both to 10 didn't work for me so I left it like that.

Hope it helps.